# Exiting awk with error code if pattern not found

Tags: awk

A common awk usecase for me is testing the output of a program and making sure a line in there exists and prints the expected value. As an example, the line may be `pattern number` and the awk tests if `number` is less than or equal to a certain value, say 100. The problem is that if the program changes the output so `pattern` is not printed any more, a naive awk program (`awk '/pattern/ {exit $2 > 100}'`) "succeeds" and does not do what it's supposed to.

I know a way to "fix" this, eg. `awk '/pattern/ {c = $2 > 100 ? 2 : 1} END {exit c ? c - 1 : 2}'` or use grep with awk but this seems wordy and inelegant, not to mention hard to remember to do. Is there an easier, more natural way? Perhaps even with something other than awk?

Comment: `"succeeds" and does not do what it's supposed to.` why not? I would invert it, tho `exit !($2>100)`. Soo, you have a solution, you may just `exit !c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are after is the following logic:

```
awk -v c=2 '/pattern/{c=!($2<100)}END{exit c}'
```

by setting the default value of `c` to 2, you have a default exit status of 2 when the value of `pattern` is not found. If `pattern` is found, it will overwrite the value with 1 if `$2 >= 100` and `0` if `$2 < 100`.

Answer (score 0):

> Exiting awk with error code if pattern not found

If you want:

| state | exit status |
| --- | --- |
| no /pattern/ | nonzero |
| number lower or equal 100 | nonzero |
| number greater then 100 | zero |

Then don't `?2:1`. The result of `$2 > 100` going to be zero or one anyway:

```
awk '/pattern/{c = $2 > 100} END{exit !c}'
```

Comment: "It's going to be zero or one anyway" - Not sure what you mean. You can have more than one error exit code, helps distinguish between different errors.